# Getting relevant data with queryAll YII2

Tags: yii2

In `my _form.php` I want to create a dropdown that contains names of relevant users (relevant = users with the role "releaseManager".
This is the code:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'Assignee')->dropDownList([$assignees = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT username FROM user, auth_assignment WHERE id=user_id AND item_name="releaseManager"')
        ->queryAll()]);
```

The problem is that along with the correct names I also get numbers.

For example: I have 2 relevant names, so I get 2 rows of 0 before the first name and a row with "1" before the second. As if it states the place in the array or I don't know what..
I tried using `queryScalar()` but then I get only one name instead of 2.
I will really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be you need `ArrayHelper::map()`

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

<?php 
    echo $form->field($model, 'Assignee')->
    dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Yii::$app->db->
        createCommand('SELECT username FROM user, auth_assignment WHERE id=user_id AND item_name="releaseManager"')
    ->queryAll(), 'username', 'username')); 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For re-usability we can also create separate method in model:

```
public function getUserNames()
{
    $usernames = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT username FROM user, auth_assignment WHERE id=user_id AND item_name="releaseManager"')
                ->queryAll();
  $result = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($usernames, 'user_id', 'username'); 
  return $result;
}
```

**Form**

```
echo $form->field($model, 'Assignee')->dropDownList(PathTOModel/ModelName::getUserNames())
```